# Command silk_clear_request_log doesn't delete anything

Tags: django, database

I am running Silk on my staging server. I want to clear space in this database, so I run the following command.

```
../../bin/python manage.py silk_clear_request_log --settings ServiceName.settings.staging
```

I expect to see output that it deletes things, but I don't get any output. After a few seconds, the prompt returns. No data is cleared in the database.

What could be causing this behavior? How would I start debugging this issue?

Comment: It seems like I had to wait for an hour before it was actually done. Is this normal?